# Looking for a 'high level' Graphics editor for Mac. Then convert diagram to TiKZ code.

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, editors

I am trying to make a large assortment of VERY basic graphs for including in my documents. (squares with the sides labeled, circles, etc...).

It seems the TiKZ package is what I want to use. Does anyone know of a point and click type editor for a Macintosh I can use to generate code for TiKZ. I found I can do this with geogebra, but it does not seem suited for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 5):

I have no experience with any particular graphic editor with the ability to generate a TikZ code, but you might want to look through [this page](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/), especially the section "Tools that generate PGF/TikZ code".

Comment: After reading through it by myself, inkscape2tikz might be just suitable as it allows you to export from Inkscape.

http://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at that page and it was referencing a lot of terms that I didn't understand. I will find out what Inkscape is exactly.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your purpose, you might consider investigating a program called [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/). It allows you to design diagrams and export directly to Tikz. Actually, it will export the raw PGF data.
It runs on

- Mac (X11 Environment Required)
- Windows
- Linux
  [image: Dia Running in X11 Environment on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4]