# List of TikZ Editor

Tags: tikz-pgf, big-list

After mentioning `TikZ` in [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/5099/3926), I tried to have a look here for recommended editors for `TikZ`. I found no list, and thus here's the question:

**What `TikZ` editors/front-ends do you know? What can you recommend?**

I guess that what I have in mind is a tool where the image can be edited using an interface similar to [inkscape](http://inkscape.org/), and then it will generate a code snippet in `TikZ`. For example I know of [geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org/cms/), but I'm interested in a big list.

I am aware of the list available [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/resources/), as pointed by one of the answers to this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14059/412), but I'm interested in some evaluation of each based on personal experience.

I suggest that each tool should has its own answer, this way this will become sort of a poll as well. Probably, each answer should contain at least: pros/cons/platform...

Comment: Does `vi` count? :-)

Comment: Without starting any wars ;) all tools are welcome!

Comment: Related, maybe even duplicate: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24235)

Comment: Also related: [What GUI applications are there to assist in generating graphics for TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26972/what-gui-applications-are-there-to-assist-in-generating-graphics-for-tex)

Comment: Does Emacs + AUCTeX count? `:)`

Comment: Perhaps the question could be clarified to exclude answers which are also answers to the question 'which editors/IDEs are available for TeX?' Obviously, any such editor is suitable for TiKZ and I suspect that is what most of us use, but I assume this question is concerned with software which is not also a general TeX editor?

Comment: @m0nhawk It's not a duplicate, an TikZ editor might be useful independent from WYSIWYG. For example, help in writing, syntax checks, preview, ...

Answer (score 21):

**TikzEdt**

This is a wonderful editor for TikZ graphics. It has a live preview, several code snippets and examples and parses the TikZ elements to some degree so that for example nodes can be marked in the live preview. Additionally this parsing allows the direct manipulation of some elements, you can drag nodes around in the preview window and the code is updated accordingly.

While the current version 0.2.1 is still a bit rough here and there it works nicely on Windows with a preliminary Linux version.

http://www.tikzedt.org/

[image: Tikzedt]

Comment: Recently I got the error "Checking for new version failed: Errore del server remoto: (404) Non trovato." that means "remote server non found". I have TikzEdt version 0.2.3.0 with Windows 10. Is it a problem of TikzEdt site or mine? Until few weeks ago all worked well.

Comment: This app was [last updated](https://code.google.com/archive/p/tikzedt/downloads) in 2013... is there still development support behind this?

Comment: Waiting for a working linux version (currently it doesn't work for me in ubuntu; i hope i only face this issue)

Comment: The download link on the site does not work anymore

Answer (score 10):

[GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/) offers TikZ export (File -> Export -> Graphics View as PGF/TikZ).

**Advantages:**

1. WYSIWIG editor, you don't need to remember TikZ commands and syntax.
2. GeoGebra is a powerful tool for drawing 2D diagrams and hence it migh make you faster than when editing plain TikZ.

**Disadvantages**

1. You need an external program.
2. The export has slight problems with labels sometimes (they get shifted a bit). But this can be easily manually fixed in the exported TikZ code.
3. It can be slow on ARM* machines i.e. Raspberry machines, due to source code environment.

Comment: There is an Online version of GeoGebra so this is an amazing advantage by itself.

Comment: Some more disadvantages
**4.** Limited support for reuse: This will disappear if geogebra's export become smarter. eg: export dependent objects as they are.  
**5.** Lack of support for styles: I am afraid this will be more permanent. But one can edit the exported tikz script; this would still save time

Answer (score 8):

Inkscape allows you to edit the image using an interface remarkably similar to Inkscape's, It can then generate TiKZ code.

Advantages: interface really is very like that of Inkscape.

Disadvantages: tends to produce unwieldy code which is not at all readable and may be difficult to modify.

Disclaimer: I've used Inkscape and I've used TiKZ but, while I have generated TiKZ code using Inkscape, I wouldn't recommend it in general.

Comment: I tried to do so. It's very easy but, as you mentioned, it's far from being clean and understandable code.
I'd say it's a last resource if one wants to have a nice looking TikZ image, but hasn't the time to create it by themselves in TikZ.

Comment: @gbernardi But you must admit, it satisfies the interface-like-Inkscape requirement to perfection!

Comment: Yes, I do. I was not trying to diminish the value of such great addon. Just pointing out something I noticed that could mainly be detrimental for the compilation time of the generated TikZ pictures ;)

As a matter of fact, I should have added that I tested it for some toy examples that were rather intricated: I vectorized a raster icon I liked (which had quite an irregular outline) in Inkscape, and converted it to TikZ.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you, you know. I was only joking.

Comment: I'm confused ... Inkscape has an interface remarkably similar to Inkscape's? Did you mean to use a different name for the first instance?

Answer (score 6):

There is another editor which does live preview: [QTikZ](https://github.com/fhackenberger/ktikz) (QT version of KTikZ)

Answer (score 5):

[KTi*k*Z](http://www.hackenberger.at/blog/ktikz-editor-for-the-tikz-language/) is a front-end based on KDE4. It is the KDE version of the generic QT4 front-end mentioned in [Dohn Joe's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/217816/).

Answer (score 0):

[cirkuit](https://github.com/KDE/cirkuit) is a front-end for Ti*k*Z, GNUplot and Circuit Macros (whatever they are). I assume from the package name in the AUR that this is based on QT5 and intended for use in Plasma.

Comment: not in development anymore is it