# Creating figures in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams

Sorry if this doubles some other question, but I failed to find the right answer.

I am using LaTeX for writing math papers. However my knowledge of LaTeX and other computer programs is rather limited. In particular I have no experience at all in drawing figures. Now I am trying to figure out where to start learning this.

I have heard that there are programs allowing to create a figure and then encapsulate it into a LaTeX file. **What are the user friendly programs of that kind?** The type of figures I would like to create include knots, polytopes, convex bodies which I can easily draw by hand, but have no idea how to do it on a computer.

Given my modest background in computers, I would prefer something which is not very sophisticated and which could be learned and used relatively quickly. (I work with Windows, if it is important.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [List of TikZ Editor](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80418/list-of-tikz-editor)

Comment: Check that question. It may have an answer for your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to have a list of WYSIWYG graphic programs that let you output (e.g., TikZ) latex code?

Comment: Also, here is the good question too: [What You See is What You Get (WYSIWYG) for PGF/TikZ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz).

Comment: @Closers This question of a first user is just a few minutes old. It might need a little clarification. But a list of TikZ editors is a partial answer at best and *not* a duplicate.

Comment: Maybe `inkscape` could be a program for you? It allows you to easily draw all kinds of stuff and an `inkscape to TikZ exporter` (see here: https://code.google.com/p/inkscape2tikz/) does exist (however, I never tried it).

Comment: I don't agree that this is a duplicate. The question asks for programs to generate figures (plots). Apart from the title, it isn't even specified that it should be done with LaTeX, only included. MKO, please elaborate a bit on the question at hand.

Comment: In addition to the above mentioned TiKZ editors and inkscape, there's also [flowframtk](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/) which can export to `pgf` code. This can be input into a LaTeX document using `\input` (with `\usepackage{pgf}`).

Comment: and you can see pgf's doc https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: Why not draw them by hand and import them instead?

Comment: There is an early question which has been update as early as a year ago with very helpful information http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-graphics-packages-are-there-for-creating-graphics-in-latex-documents

Comment: There is also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26972/15925

Comment: You might event want to have a look to [Why draw diagrams using LaTeX when there are open source tools like OpenOffice?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102590/13304)