# Software for generating Flow charts / mind maps where labels include latex?

Tags: equations, mindmaps, flow-charts, software

I'd like make some mind maps/flow charts that include equations, which I'd like to write in latex. One problem is that generating those in tikz or any other graphical package directly in latex is not very visual and does take a long time.

Is there a software that lets you draw boxes/arrows via WYSIWYG editor but still allows for latex formulas in those boxes?

EDIT: I'm using Windows.

Comment: You should specify what is your operating system.

Comment: Of course, I'm using windows, thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Inkscape, if you can get it for Windows.

Comment: @cfr There is an Inkscape version for Windows, I've got it installed on Windows 10! :)

Comment: Oh I didn't know about the use of latex + inkscape, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a dedicated program for it, but you can try [TikzEdt](http://www.tikzedt.org/). It is not perfect, but will probably make your life a bit easier.

Also see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80418/list-of-tikz-editor) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz) for more answers/options.

Comment: IMO TikzEdt is the best but unfortunately I think the project is dead. You can use it but don't wait for an update... I hope someone will receive the inheritance and will continue to develop it!

Comment: @CarLaTeX that is true unfortunately.