# Create tikz image from image template

Tags: tikz-pgf

Which tikz tool can be used to create a tikz image from a image template? for example, I have a png file as below, I just want to create the same image with tikz. Maybe tool to load the image firstly, then draw on it to get tikz code, then remove the original image to get a tikz copy.

[image]

Comment: No special "tool" (actually, what you mean with this?) is necessary. Just start to draw ... by help of TikZ & PGF manual this should not be difficult. If you will stuck in some detail, ask here, how to solve your problem.

Comment: Doing such things manually will give better code, but it is a possibility to trace an image in Inkscape (either manually or automatically), and then export to TikZ code from Inkscape.

Comment: Try a WYSIWYG TikZ editor.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80418/82389

Comment: @SkeletonBow: do you have any suggestions about WYSIWYG-TikZ-editors?  Any experiences?  I think, the OP did exactly want to know, which WYSIWYG-editors exist.  Just answering: try one is not really helpful?

Comment: @Jan I've only used [this one,](http://www.tikzedt.org) but it seems like there is a [question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24235/what-you-see-is-what-you-get-wysiwyg-for-pgf-tikz) with a list, which is nice! Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Even though there is a way to draw on an image, however, it is much simpler to draw the diagram directly if you have all the details which in your case, it seems to me you have it. Drawing your diagram is trivial and can be easily done by Tikz. This is a result of the following code

[image]

```
\documentclass[border={10pt}]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[very thick,rounded corners] 
(-.2,.2) -- (8.2,0.2) -- (8.2,-1.2) -- (7.2,-2.2) -- (0.8,-2.2) -- (-.2,-1.2) -- cycle;
\draw[thin,rounded corners] 
(-.1,.1) -- (8.1,0.1) -- (8.1,-1.1) -- (7.1,-2.1) -- (0.9,-2.1) -- (-.1,-1.1) -- cycle;
\fill[gray!20, draw=black, very thick,rounded corners] 
(0,0) -- (8,0) -- (8,-1) -- (7,-2) -- (1,-2) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;

\draw[thick] (2,.2) -- ( 2.1,.28) -- (2.4,.28) -- (2.5,.2);
\draw[thick] (3.75,.2) -- ( 3.85,.28) -- (4.15,.28) -- (4.25,.2);
\draw[thick] (6,.2) -- ( 5.9,.28) -- (5.6,.28) -- (5.5,.2);

\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black] (2,-.01) rectangle (6,-1);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black] (1,.9)   rectangle (1.6,0.22);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black] (6.4,.9) rectangle (7,0.22);
\filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (2.2,-.5) rectangle node[yshift=1.6cm]{\Large 5} (2.6,-1.3) ;
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]  (2.2,-1.3) rectangle (2.6,-1.6);
\filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (3.0,-.5) rectangle node[yshift=1.6cm]{\Large 4} (3.4,-1.3);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]  (3.0,-1.3) rectangle (3.4,-1.6);
\filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (3.8,-.5) rectangle node[yshift=1.6cm]{\Large 3} (4.2,-1.3);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]  (3.8,-1.3) rectangle (4.2,-1.6);
\filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (4.6,-.5) rectangle node[yshift=1.6cm]{\Large 2}(5.0,-1.3);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]  (4.6,-1.3) rectangle (5.0,-1.6);
\filldraw[fill=yellow, draw=black] (5.4,-.5) rectangle node[yshift=1.6cm]{\Large 1} (5.8,-1.3);
\filldraw[fill=white, draw=black]  (5.4,-1.3) rectangle (5.8,-1.6);
\node at (4,-2.8) {\textbf{Micro USB Male connector}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very well done.

Comment: instead of your last `\node`-command, use this code `\node at (2.2, .8) {\textbf{5}};
\node at (3, .8) {\textbf{4}};
\node at (3.8, .8) {\textbf{3}};
\node at (4.6, .8) {\textbf{2}};
\node at (5.4, .8) {\textbf{1}};`.  This will place the numbers directly above the yellow connectors.

Comment: @Jan, Oops. I was up all the night. You're right about numbers. I wasn't paying attention to them but a better way is to place a node above the rectangle and shift it up. see my update. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, for the three round polygons, can we just draw one then shrink it a little bit to create the other two? Since the shape is the same but size different, I guess it's doable but not sure.

Comment: @lucky1928, why you wanna do so?